# Exponential Integrals: What is the integral of the exponential integral $E_1(x)$?

Tags: integration, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

The exponential integral is defined as: $$E_n=x^{n-1} \int_x^\infty{\frac{e^{-t}}{t^n}}dt.$$
I want to prove the relation: $$\int_0^xE_1(t)dt=1-E_2(x)$$
Integrating $E_{n-1}=-\frac{dE_n}{dx}$ from $0$ to $x$ with $n=2$, I got to: $$\int_0^xE_1(t)dt=E_2(0)-E_2(x).$$
I can't see how $E_2(0)$ will equal $1$. Looking at the definition, it should equal $0$.

Can you please point out what I did wrong?

Comment: We are interested in 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t^2} dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is the $\Gamma(-1)$ which is a singularity of the gamma function whose residue is $1$ ... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Residues

So the limit as $x$ tends to $0$ gives $1$.

Comment: What about the $x$ outside the integral? It will always make $lim_{\tau \to 0}E_2(\tau)=0$, won't it?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{\tau}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t^2} dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
will be have like $\frac{1}{\tau}$ as $\tau$ tends $0$.

Comment: $$E_2(x)=x \int_x^\infty{\frac{e^{-t}}{t^2}}dt,$$ so: $$\lim_{\tau \to 0}E_2(\tau)=\lim_{\tau \to 0}\bigl(\tau \int_\tau^\infty{\frac{e^{-t}}{t^2}}dt\bigr).$$ This $\tau$ before the integral will be $0$ in the limit, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: 
$$\lim_{\tau \to 0}E_2(\tau)=\lim_{\tau \to 0}\bigl(\tau \int_\tau^\infty{\frac{e^{-t}}{t^2}}dt\bigr).$$

Now let $t= \tau u$ and change the limits of integration: 
$$\lim_{\tau \to 0}E_2(\tau)=\lim_{\tau \to 0}\bigl(\tau \int_{1}^\infty{\frac{e^{-\tau u}}{\tau^2u^2}}\tau du\bigr)= \int_{1}^\infty{\frac{du}{u^2}},$$
which is easily seen to be $\color{red}{1}$.